# How to access named JSON array with Javascript

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, parsing

I am getting a JSON array from an API.  The returned data is written to console:

```
console.log(` data [${data}] `);
```

which prints:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {                
            "create_date": "1/30/2023 07:43 AM",
            "description": "0800",
            "override_user_id": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "user_id": 32,
            "user_type": 0
        },
        {                
            "create_date": "1/30/2023 09:43 AM",
            "description": "1000",                
            "override_user_id": -1,                
            "type": 1,
            "user_id": 32,
            "user_type": 0
        },
        {                
            "create_date": "1/30/2023 11:43 AM",
            "description": "1200",                
            "override_user_id": -1,                
            "type": 1,
            "user_id": 32,
            "user_type": 0
        },
        {                
            "create_date": "1/30/2023 01:43 PM",
            "description": "1400",                
            "override_user_id": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "user_id": 32,
            "user_type": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am expecting.  But if I check the length (**expecting length of 4**)

```
console.log(`data [${data.length}] `);
```

I get:

```
data [607]
```

Which does not make sense to me.  Furthermore, if I write the named array to console

```
console.log(` data [${data.aaData}] `);
```

I get:

```
data [undefined]
```

And, if I attempt to access the properties of the objects in the array I get undefined for each.

console.log(`description = [${data.aaData[i].description}]`);

I get

```
description = [undefined]
```

`data` is the variable returned from JQuery ajax call

```
success: function (data) {
...
```

Given that it prints directly to console without having to `stringfy` it, the returned data should be the string version of the json object.  However, if I apply

```
console.log(` data[${JSON.parse(data)}] `);
```

displays

```
data [undefined]
```

> What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `data` is a `string` so `data.length` will return the length of the string which is 607 in your case. To convert the data to JSON, add `dataType: 'json'` to the `$.ajax()` options like so:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```